# Insufficient Memory Error: Bag of Words OpenCV 2.4.6 Visual Studio 2010

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, computer-vision, k-means, feature-extraction

I am implementing the Bag of words Model using SURF and SIFT features and SVM Classifier. I want to train(80% of 2876 images) and test(20% of 2876 images) it. I have kept dictionarySize set to 1000. My Computer configuration is intel Xeon(2 processors)/ 32GB RAM/ 500GB HDD. Here, images are read whenever necessary instead of storing them.
like,

```
    std::ifstream file("C:\\testFiles\\caltech4\\train0.csv", ifstream::in);
    if (!file) 
    {
        string error_message = "No valid input file was given, please check the given filename.";
        CV_Error(CV_StsBadArg, error_message);
    }
    string line, path, classlabel;
    printf("\nReading Training images................\n");
    while (getline(file, line)) 
    {
        stringstream liness(line);
        getline(liness, path, separator);
        getline(liness,classlabel);
        if(!path.empty()) 
        {
            Mat image = imread(path, 0);


            cout << " " << path << "\n";
            detector.detect(image, keypoints1);
            detector.compute(image, keypoints1,descriptor1);
            featuresUnclustered.push_back(descriptor1); 
        }
    }
```

Here, the train0.csv contains the paths to the images with the labels. It stops from this loop while reading the images, computing the descriptor and adding it to the features to be clustered. Following error apprears on the console:

[image]

Comment: Image loading seems fine. probably is the featuresUnclestered that is too big

Comment: How do i use featuresUnclustered as I want to use whole dataset?

Comment: Well, you first can check if the problem is really that.

Comment: it works fine with small dataset of 500 images.

Comment: Is there any way to increase the memory allocated to it as there is in Weka?

Answer (score 0):

Here, in the code, I re-sized images being read to the dimension 256*256; the requirement of the memory is reduced. Ergo, the error disappeared.

```
        Mat image = imread(path, 0);
        resize(image,image,Size(256,256));
        cout << " " << path << "\n";
        detector.detect(image, keypoints1);
        detector.compute(image, keypoints1,descriptor1);
        featuresUnclustered.push_back(descriptor1);
```

But, it might appear with bigger dataset.